# flex compiler error in IntellijIdea

Tags: flash, apache-flex, intellij-idea

I have a rather strange Error when trying to compile some flash application in IntellijIdea 13. First time compilation was successful but second time I have a such Error:

Error:Flash Resource Builder: /root/IdeaProjects/flare3Dexp/out/production/flare3Dexp/history (Is a directory)

I don't have any idea how to solve it. Google also can't help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure in IntelliJ File->Settings : Compiler -> Flex Compiler : Compile with: Built-in compiler shell is selected?

Comment: Thank you for help. I was some strange which stop repeating after I reboot system